# Why are the following two solutions to Factorial Trailing Zeroes not equivalent?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working on the Factorial Trailing Zeroes problem on a OJ website. I googled the problem and some solutions came up:

```
int solution1(int n) {
  int result = 0;
  while (n > 0) {
    result += n /= 5;
  }
  return result;
}

int solution2(int n) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 5;n >= i; i *= 5) {
    result += n/i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Despite the details in implementation, I think the rationale is the same, which can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-trailing-zeroes-factorial-number/). And I thus assume the two solutions are equivalent. But when I submit them, it turns out that solution2 passed 500 out of 502 test cases and yielded the wrong answer(result=452137080) when n=1808548329, whereas solution1 yielded the right answer(result=452137076).

Now I am confused where goes wrong here. Can anyone tell me why the two solutions above are not equivalent? And why solution1 is right and solution2 is wrong?

Comment: I don't think solution1 is right because it contains infinite loop.

Comment: sorry for mistyped. the while loop in solution1 should be  result += n /= 5; Thanks.

Comment: Based on the answer you get, I'd guess that `i` in the second function is `unsigned`. (Or perhaps `size_t` on a 32-bit platform.)

Comment: 'mistyped'?  Why did you not coy/paste it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `i *= 5` can overflow. And when it overflows, you no longer have a correct comparison with `n`.

Say n=1808548329. Here's what happens:

```
             i              n      correct i
   -----------     ----------   ------------
             5     1808548329              5
            25     1808548329             25
           125     1808548329            125
           625     1808548329            625
          3125     1808548329           3125
         15625     1808548329          15625
         78125     1808548329          78125
        390625     1808548329         390625
       1953125     1808548329        1953125
       9765625     1808548329        9765625
      48828125     1808548329       48828125
     244140625     1808548329      244140625
    1220703125     1808548329     1220703125
    1808548329     1808548329     6103515625 # i overflows here; loop should stop
     452807053     1808548329    30517578125
   -2030932031     1808548329   152587890625
   -1564725563     1808548329   762939453125
     766306777     1808548329  3814697265625
    -463433411     1808548329 19073486328125
    1977800241     1808548329 95367431640625
```

I generated the above with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n = 1808548329;
  int i = 1;
  long long l = 1;
  do {
    i *= 5;
    l *= 5;
    printf("%14d %14d %14lld\n", i, n, l);
  } while (n >= i);
  return 0;
}
```

(In the original code, some of the `n/i` values will be negative, just to make the situation more confusing. I didn't include an `n/i` column; it might be amusing to do that.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AllenWang: The fact that the overflowed power-of-five is exactly the test case suggests that whoever designed the test had precisely this bug in mind. There are a few things one could learn from this question, none of which have much to do with the original problem. One of them is that a lot of the code which you find with a Google search actually has subtle bugs in it, so it should not be relied upon. Another is that a for loop with anything other than a simple increment-by-one is suspect; and even the increment-by-one can overflow if the limit is INTMAX.

Comment: Thank you again for your patience and insightful advise. When I first encountered this problem, it occurred to me that overflowing may lead to the confusing results. But I checked the code but found nothing susceptible. So I didn't dig deeper. Well I've still got a lot to learn. :)